Set heroku remote to sub folder in git repo
In my git repo I have both folders
--client
--server

I want to add the server only to heroku
but when adding the
heroku git:remote -a <my-heroku-app-name>

This add the heroku to all git repo and not the server only
How can I add just sub directory in an existing git repo to heroku
Thanks

That's now how remotes work, but you can push a subtree as shown in the duplicate question.
